# Safe to convert OS in .uif to .iso?

Tags: operating-systems, compression

I'm being sent Windows 7 in a .uif format. Is it okay to convert it to .iso so it can be installed from a USB? If so, what is the best way to do that?

Comment: Try this http://www.uiftoiso.com/ and then use http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool to write the iso to a USB drive

Comment: Thanks @kobaltz, that's more help than I was asking for. Also, as an aside, is it suspicious that the .uif is 6gb, whereas Windows 7 in .iso seems to be 2gb (from what I can find on the internet).

Comment: If your friend created the UIF from the DVD, it could have been uncompressed and did a bit by bit copy of the DVD which could result in a much larger file. If you don't want to go through this hassle, you can download an official iso from http://www.heidoc.net/joomla/technology-science/microsoft/14-windows-7-direct-download-links